# Information about computer in python

Tags: python, windows, system

How would i go about gathering information about a system in python? Seems most of the commands are made for Unix... Are there any options in windows?

Thanks,

Jake.

Comment: What exactly do you want information on?  Processor type, memory?  Hostname?  What do you mean "options" for windows?

Comment: Stuff like that. Mainly hostname, processor type, cwd and so on...

Comment: Be more specific, otherwise the question cannot be answered. List exactly those pieces of information that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the [platform module](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Getting system information under Windows (Python)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511491/), from ActiveState code recipes.

Answer (score 0):

This page highlights the list of infos you can get from the OS and for each tells you the OS availability.

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html

Also check out this page

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511491-getting-system-information-under-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Try the `os` module.  [link](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html)